# Convert docx to qmd

Tags: r, quarto, rewriting

I want to know if there is a way to convert docx to qmd files. I routinely write in qmd then render the file to docx and send it to reviewers and co-autohrs. They edit some parts then send it back to me to apply changes. It would be great if there is a way to convert their revised version to qmd so I can continue working on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is one of the open ends with the Rmd/qmd workflow. There was some work a while back with the package {redoc}. I have not tried the docx --> md path suggested below. One of the issues is that MS Word provides some wild formatting options (that may break with any conversion). But I would love to have a docx --> qmd feature as well as in today's world it is still common place to have colleagues / commenters working with mainstream docx.

Answer (score 0):

We can't convert docx into qmd file. First we have to make it into md and then by copy pasting the content in that md file into new qmd doc we can convert into qmd.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install Pandoc and the Quarto package. By then, you can convert the docx to markdown file using the command line:

```
pandoc input.docx -f docx -t markdown -o output.md
```

and then md file to quarto file:

```
quarto render --to quarto output.md
```

See if you can work it out.